# Cellpadding for longtable wanted

Tags: longtable

When using the `tabular` environment I used `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}` in order to get a decent cell-padding. I now switched to `longtable` environment and there the command has no effect. Anyone knows how to do cell-padding in a `longtable` environment?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}` should work in exactly the same way. If you have a case that doesn't seem to work you should always make a complete (small) docuemnt that shows the problem

Comment: Works, the problem is that there is a graphic in the row that is bigger than the text content. This is why I thought the cellpadding does not work. The solution for me was to add `\renewcommand\extrarowheight{0.1cm}` in order to expand the row height.